# How to import multiple images via Tensorflow python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, jpeg

I've had a lot of difficulty for the past few days trying to import images from my desktop into Tensorflow. I've looked at the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data) and searched for some [online tutorials](https://gist.github.com/eerwitt/518b0c9564e500b4b50f), however, my luck has been quite low and I haven't been able to understand much of what I've read. My attempts to create a function to import images from what little I've understood has been unsurprisingly unsuccessful. The following is what I've done so far. After running it through a debugger, I see that the program is getting stuck on the first line. The Tensorflow API says that I must pass a file pattern or a 1D tensor of file patterns. Isn't the file path I've given a file pattern?

```
def import_data():

    image_path = tf.train.match_filenames_once("C:\Users\ratno\Desktop\honest chaos\*.JPG")
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(image_path)

    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

    _, content = reader.read(filename_queue)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=1)
    cropped_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, 3000, 3000)
    reduced_image = tf.image.resize_images(cropped_image, [100, 100])
    modified_image = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(reduced_image, [10000, 1]))

    return modified_image
```

The code is supposed to take in a slew of jpgs from a folder on my desktop and convert them from RGB jpgs to grayscale jpgs. Afterwards, it'll take the grayscale jpgs, and crop them to 3000x3000 pixel sizes, and use tf.resize_images to further reduce them to 100x100 pixel images. Finally, it'll return everything in the form of a 1x10000 shaped tensor.

Thanks in advance.
And if there are any suggestions for other parts of the code, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

To read multiple images in a single call to session.run simply call reader.read() many times. Alternatively, you can call it once and use tf.train.batch once you're done processing to get a minibatch of images.

Answer (score 1):

```
def _parse_function(filename):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.cond(
        tf.image.is_jpeg(image_string),
        lambda: tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3),
        lambda: tf.image.decode_png(image_string, channels=3))
    image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [90, 90])
    return image_resized
filenames = ["/var/data/image1.jpg", "/var/data/image2.jpg", ...]
labels = [0, 37, 29, 1, ...]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can this function work with 4000 images?